# List of general links

Tags: fieldtype

Umbraco has a type that allows a content editor to add a list of either external/internal links to a document type. The list of links can then be displayed in a view to a user.

[image: Umbraco Link List]

Is there a field type in sitecore that can generate a list of general links.

The closest thing I have found is this https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Field_Suite.aspx but I need it to work with version 8.2

Comment: see if this works for you: http://josedbaez.com/2017/03/sitecore8-link-list/. It's an updated version of https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Link_List_Field_Type.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I would do this using the Express SubItem module from the market place. https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Express_Subitem.aspx

With this module you can create a child template with the general link on, but instead of adding child items, you can control it all from the parent item.

[image]

Then when it comes to rendering that out, you can use out of the box Sitecore code to do that and you don't have to worry about maintaining a field suite with upgrades etc...

I have used this module a few times and it has worked out well.

Comment: As great as this module is, I've worked with it extensively and can tell you that it has MANY issues. Please avoid this module.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist this functionality OOTB. 
One option is to get from github the source code of Field Suite and to update to Sitecore 8.2 (https://github.com/Velir/SitecoreFieldSuite/tree/master ) 
Is not an easy task because on Sitecore 8 was introduced Speak.

Other option is to implement something with same functionality in this way:

You have a template named Link that contains a field of type GeneralLink. You create items of type Link under a folder "Site Links".

On the items where do you want to have External/Internal Links you will have a MultiList field with a Datasource witch point to Site Links folder item;

Is not the most elegant way but if you educate editors they can leave with it. And if you upgrade in the future you will not have any problems because is OOTB functionality.

Comment: I think for simplicity, I will need to go down the template route. Thank you for your help

Comment: what do you mean : go down template route?