# Iterating through a linklist in sitecore via a powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions

ive currently got a powershell script in sitecore which goes through the Home directory and changes the target value for all general links to "Active browser"

What i would now like to do is also change the target values for all internal links in a **link list.**

Current script:

```
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {

# Get items
$root = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/SiteName"
# Get its descendents


$allItems = @( ($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item))

# Get all
$allItems = @($root) + @(($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item))

$allItems | ForEach-Object {
# Get the items
$currentItem = $_
# Get item fields and create loop
$currentItem.Fields | ForEach-Object {
    
    #Check the field type
    if ($_.type -eq "Linklist")
    {
        [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
        # Update target for Internal Links
        if ($linkField.Linktype -eq 'internal')
        {
            $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
            $linkField.target = ""
            $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()
        }
    if ($_.type -eq "General Link")
    {
        [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $currentItem.Fields[$_.name]
        # Update target for Internal Links
        if ($linkField.Linktype -eq 'internal')
        {
            $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
            $linkField.target = ""
            $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()
        }
    }
}
}  
}
```

Can anyone help? thanks!!

EDIT- see image below for the list type:
[image]

Comment: Hi @SumitBhatia the list type is "linklist". See my edits in the description :)

Comment: What Sitecore version you are using? It looks like a custom field type.

Comment: im using sitecore version 10. its basically a list, so im thinking will need to iterate through it - similar to a multi list

Comment: @user13705 please provide an example raw field value of containing more than one link. LinkList is a custom field type, which aims to solve a commonly requested feature of being able to add n number of links without specifying a new field for each link (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853366/sitecore-link-list-field-type and 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7701/list-of-general-links). If you can share where you got the field from, that will help. IIRC, the LinkList field stores values in XML format.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to get the Link List field type in a variable. For this, you can create a sample script and target only a single item to access the link list field. Once you get the desired result then create a loop like this in your actual logic given above.

```
# Assuming $linksList is your list of items containing links
$linksList | ForEach-Object {
    $linkItem = $_
    
    # Access link-related fields 
    [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $linkItem.Fields[$_.name]

    # Your logic for each link item goes here
    Write-Host "Processing link"

    $linkItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $linkField.target = ""
    $$linkItem.Editing.EndEdit()
    
    # Add more logic as needed
}
```

Or if `$linksList` is giving you the raw values like ID of the item then get the item in the above logic and use the same code in your script to update the target.

Hope this will help.